# Beautifulsoup - How to get all links inside a block with a certain class?

Tags: python, python-2.7, beautifulsoup

I have the following HTML Dom:

```
    <div class="meta-info meta-info-wide"> <div class="title">Разработчик</div> <div class="content contains-text-link"> 

<a class="dev-link" href="http://www.jourist.com&amp;sa=D&amp;usg=AFQjCNHiC-nLYHAJwNnvDyYhyoeB6n8YKg" rel="nofollow" target="_blank">Перейти на веб-сайт</a>

 <a class="dev-link" href="mailto:info@jourist.com" rel="nofollow" target="_blank">Написать: info@jourist.com</a> 

 <div class="content physical-address">Diagonalstraße 41
    20537 Hamburg</div> </div> </div>
```

I need to get all links(url) with class `dev-link` inside block `div.meta-info-wide`.

I tried this obvious way, but does not work:

```
divTag = soup.find_all("div", {"class":"meta-info-wide"})
        print(len(divTag))

        for tag in divTag:
            tdTags = tag.find_all("a", {"class":"dev-link"})
            for tag in tdTags:
                print tag.text
```

Comment: you code works fine. I use python3 and bs4.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try the following:

```
import bs4

html = """    
<div class="meta-info meta-info-wide"> <div class="title">Разработчик</div> <div class="content contains-text-link"> 
<a class="dev-link" href="http://www.jourist.com&amp;sa=D&amp;usg=AFQjCNHiC-nLYHAJwNnvDyYhyoeB6n8YKg" rel="nofollow" target="_blank">Перейти на веб-сайт</a>
<a class="dev-link" href="mailto:info@jourist.com" rel="nofollow" target="_blank">Написать: info@jourist.com</a> 
<div class="content physical-address">Diagonalstraße 4120537 Hamburg</div> </div> </div>"""

soup = bs4.BeautifulSoup(html, "html.parser")

for div in soup.find_all("div", {"class":"meta-info-wide"}):
    for link in div.select("a.dev-link"):
        print link['href']
```

This gives you:

```
http://www.jourist.com&sa=D&usg=AFQjCNHiC-nLYHAJwNnvDyYhyoeB6n8YKg
mailto:info@jourist.com
```

The [`select()`](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#searching-by-css-class) is used to return all `a` tags which have the class `dev-link`. This is the recommended method to use when there are two or more CSS classes involved.

Tested with BeautifulSoup 4.5.1, Python 2.7.12

Comment: I have `from bs4 import BeautifulSoup` not simple `import bs4`

Comment: If do the following: ` c = soup.find_all("div", {"class":"meta-info-wide"})
        print(len(c))` It gives me zero(0)

Comment: Using the [`select()`](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#searching-by-css-class) statement works better when there are multiple classes used.

Comment: There isn't a problem with your way of importing, it is up to you which way you prefer.

Comment: The OP's code works, I think the problem is Python version or BeautifulSoup version.