# How to get that one href link inside the selected block with BeautifulSoup

Tags: python, html, beautifulsoup, screen-scraping

I'm trying to select a specific link inside a block using BeautifulSoup (Python 3.7). How can I select a specific link within a selected block?

This is for a job that I'm currently doing, I used selenium before, but I think there is no need for that yet.

```py
 from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
 import requests

 base_url = 'http://www.shop.pr'

 shop_urls = {'econo' : '/econo/shoppers' , 
              'pueblo' : '/pueblo/shoppers' , 
              'costco' : '/costco/shoppers' , 
              'econo' : '/econo/shoppers'}

 selected_shop = 'econo'
 append_to_url = shop_urls.get(selected_shop)

 url = base_url + append_to_url

 page = requests.get(url)

 soup = BeautifulSoup(page.text , 'html.parser')

 toString = str(soup.prettify)

 file = open('page.txt','w+')
 file.write(toString)

 wrapper = soup.find("div", {"class": "wrapper"})
 sub_wrapper = wrapper.find('div' , {'class' : 'breadcrumb-holder' })

 print(sub_wrapper)
```

After digging deeper with the code, I got to this:

```
<div class="breadcrumb-holder">
<div data-react-class="SliderPageLink" data-react-

props='{"baseLink":"/econo/shoppers/donde-mejor-se-compra-20190711/4878/product-list-view","page":1,"linkText":"VER PRODUCTOS","sliderSelector":"#shopper-terminal .catalog-view .slider","show":true,"back":false}'></div>
<ul class="breadcrumb">
<li>
<a href="/">Shoppers</a>
</li>
<li>
<a href="/econo/shoppers?clientid=1"><strong>Econo</strong>
</a></li>
</ul>
</div>
```

and later tried to get: 
    `"/econo/shoppers/donde-mejor-se-compra-20190711/4878/product-list-view"` but it returns me 'None'.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Beautifulsoup - How to get all links inside a block with a certain class?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41237467/beautifulsoup-how-to-get-all-links-inside-a-block-with-a-certain-class)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand correctly what your are looking for, this should work:

First,

```
import json
```

Then, add to the `wrapper` part of your code the following:

```
target = sub_wrapper.find('div')
td = json.loads(target['data-react-props'])
print(td['baseLink'])
```

Output:

> '/econo/shoppers/donde-mejor-se-compra-20190711/4878/product-list-view'

Answer (score 0):

`data-react-props` that you are trying to get seem to be a valid python dictionary. If so, I would suggest converting it to a dictionary using `ast.literal_eval` and then getting whatever you want.

```
import ast 
# Your code here
drp = wrapper.find('div' , {'data-react-class': 'SliderPageLink'})['data-react-props']
drp_dict = ast.literal_eval(drp.replace(':true', ':True').replace(':false', ':False'))
base_link = drp_dict['baseLink'] # Your link here
```

Use of `ast.literal_eval` seem to be safe as its doc says

```
Help on function literal_eval in module ast:

literal_eval(node_or_string)
    Safely evaluate an expression node or a string containing a Python
    expression.  The string or node provided may only consist of the following
    Python literal structures: strings, numbers, tuples, lists, dicts, booleans,
    and None.
```

However, some changes to the string may be needed, e.g. `true` isn't a python expression.